# How to iterate through an array of hashes sorting the keys in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, hash

I have an array of hashes like this:

```
items = [{"id"=>"123", "code"=>"abc","name"=>"test", "type"=>["good"]},
   {"id"=>"555", "code"=>"ddd","name"=>"foo", "type"=>["better"]},
   {"id"=>"098", "code"=>"zyx","name"=>"bar", "type"=>["best"]}]
```

I am trying to sort each hash within the array by the key.

I tried this:

```
items.each { |item| item = item.sort.to_h }
```

It returns the same result:

```
 [{"id"=>"123", "code"=>"abc", "name"=>"test", "type"=>["good"]},
 {"id"=>"555", "code"=>"ddd", "name"=>"foo", "type"=>["better"]},
 {"id"=>"098", "code"=>"zyx", "name"=>"bar", "type"=>["best"]}]
```

but when I try this:

```
items[0].sort.to_h
```

this is the result:

```
 {"code"=>"abc", "id"=>"123", "name"=>"test", "type"=>["good"]}
```

So it looks like when I call the individual elements within `items` using `items[x]` where `x` is an index value within the array, it sort it.
But I need a solution to iterate through each element doing that and saving the sort.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Use `map` instead of `each`.

Comment: As @Sagar said use `items.map { |item| item = item.sort.to_h }`

Comment: `each` returns the receiver.

Comment: Also not sure what purpose sorting a hash serves...

Comment: @SagarPandya I wish you posted the answer. what you suggested was exactly correct.

Comment: @Dark, thanks you provided more details to the exact same answer. it worked. the item = that i did was not necessary. I could have just done this items.map { |item| item.sort.to_h }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a Ruby Hash alphabetically by keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384967/how-to-sort-a-ruby-hash-alphabetically-by-keys)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with this:

```
items.map { |item| item.sort.to_h }
```

Thanks @SagarPandya and @Dark

Comment: `items.map(&:sort).map(&:to_h)`

Answer (score 0):

If, as in the example, all the hashes have the same keys, it would be faster to perform a single sort on the keys.

```
sorted_keys = items.first.keys.sort
  #=> ["code", "id", "name", "type"]
items.map { |item| sorted_keys.each_with_object({}) { |k,h| h[k] = item[k] } }
  #=> [{"code"=>"abc", "id"=>"123", "name"=>"test", "type"=>["good"]},
  #    {"code"=>"ddd", "id"=>"555", "name"=>"foo", "type"=>["better"]},
  #    {"code"=>"zyx", "id"=>"098", "name"=>"bar", "type"=>["best"]}]
```

The last line could alternatively be written

```
items.map { |item| sorted_keys.zip(item.values_at(*sorted_keys)).to_h }
```